# Bind to Control Property in ControlTemplate.Triggers Setter

Tags: c#, wpf, controltemplate

I'm implementing `ControlTemplate` for a `Button`. If the mouse is over the button, i want to change the background color to a slightly ligher color. For that purpose i implemented a `IValueConverter`, that creates a new `SolidColorBrush` based on the `Color` of an other `SolidColorBrush`.

I'm trying to use that `IValueConverter` in the `Setter` of a `Trigger`. But the `DataBinding` is not created.

```xml
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
    <!-- Custom layout omited-->
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="{Binding Background, Converter={StaticResouce myConverter}}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I already tried using a `TemplateBinding` and specifing a `{RelativeSource Self}` and `{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}`. None of that worked for reasons, that i partly figured out.

I can't use a `Style` to define the `Trigers`, since i later will reference parts of the `ControlTemplate`, that are not known to the style.

Is there any way to archive such a binding, or is that impossible?

Comment: This would somehow work with `{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}` and a Background property that is set by a Button Style Setter (but not set directly at the Button). It would however start an infinite loop of updates of the Background property, because you use the same property as Binding target and source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it work you need to use a `Style` to set the initial `Background` for the `Trigger` instead of setting it on the `Button` directly. This will remove the binding.

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="DimGray" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate
        TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Border Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
          <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </Border>

        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                   Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},  
                            Path=Background, 
                            Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}">
            </Setter>
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Instead of a converter that brightens the `Background` on mouse over it might be sufficient to manipulate the `Opacity`.

Answer (score 2):

Directly changing the `Background` property of the Button might result in an endless update loop, because the target property is the same as the source property of the Binding.

The Setter in the Trigger should instead target an element in the ControlTemplate, e.g. a top-level Border:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
    <Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        ...
    </Border>                    
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="border"
                    Property="Background"
                    Value="{Binding Background,
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                            Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```